# Python: shortening the import statements for my package

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging

My package has the following folder structure:

```
pkg/
├─ pkg/
│  ├─ module1/
│  |  ├─ __init__.py
│  |  ├─ classB.py
│  |  └─ functionB.py
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ classA.py
│  └─ functionA.py
├─ setup.py
└─ .gitignore
```

Each of the python files `classX.py` and `functionX.py` contains a single class or function with the same name as the file itself. For example, `classA.py` contains `def classA(object): [...]` and nothing else. Sometimes, I put classes and functions into separate files like that because they tend to become huge.

After I install my package in developer mode with `pip install -e .`, I have to import like this:

```py
from pkg.classA import classA
from pkg.functionA import functionA
from pkg.module1.classB import classB
from pkg.module1.functionB import functionB
```

I would prefer to import like this instead:
(other people have to use my package, so it has to be nice)

```py
from pkg import classA, functionA
from pkg.module1 import classB, functionB
```

I managed to enable the above by editing `pkg/pkg/__init__.py`:

```py
from pkg.classA import classA
from pkg.functionA import functionA
```

and by editing `pkg/pkg/module1/__init__.py`:

```py
from pkg.module1.classB import classB
from pkg.module1.functionB import functionB
```

My solution is horribly inelegant. Is there a better way to do this or am I supposed to just put the huge classes and functions together into one (possibly enormous) python file?

Comment: *I would prefer* -- Why are you expending any energy at all to think about this?  You type that once, it works forever.  What are you trying to save here?

Comment: Other people are supposed to use my package, so it has to be nice. Like numpy is nice, for example.

Comment: Numpy does the exact thing you did with `__init__.py`. That's the standard way to do it.

Comment: What you're doing with importing the symbols you want to export in `__init__.py` on the module level is exactly how this is usually done; you can also use `__all__` to define what gets imported when someone does `import * from ..`. https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/__init__.py

Comment: @MatsLindh. Beat me to it, link and everything :)

Comment: Thanks so much, @Mad Physicist and @MatsLindh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on right track, just need a little bit more optimization.

edit file `pkg/pkg/__init__.py` as

```
from .classA import classA
from .functionA import functionA
```

and file `pkg/pkg/module1/__init__.py` as

```
from .classB import classB
from .functionB import functionB
```

This will work for you, and a little bit cleaner.